# Adressing a frame out of a cgi-generated frame?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, cgi

I build a html-page with 3 frames.
My first frame contains a form with variable content in a combo-box. So i generate it with a cgi-skript.
When I submit the form I want the result of the second cgi-skript to be send in my second frame.
But it seems that i can't address the second frame by simple adding the target="framename"-attribute. I think this is because the generated frame has not the same origin as the hard coded html-page.

Does anyone know how i could send the response from my second cgi-skript to the second frame?
Or is there a way to send the response in a defined part of the html page e.g. in some script tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this isn't a "real" Problem.
I tried too do this in my local IIS and opened the html-files by double-klicking.
The problem there is, that than the cgi-script and the html-don't have the same origin (html file:///C.. and the cgi-file localhost/cgi-bin/...).
So you just have to call the html-file from the browser (localhost/...).